# Subsequence having a pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_i:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a sequence of functions, can we
have a subsequence which converges to some $f$ on $[0,1]\cap
\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Proof : Consider a some enumeration $q_1,\ q_2,\ \cdots \in
\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

So we have a subsequence, let $f_i$, s.t. $\{f_i(q_1) \}$ is
convergent. And we take a subsequence again so that $\{f_i(q_2)\}$
is convergent.

Hence we have $f : \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ s.t. $f$
is a pointwise limit of $f_i$ on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Is this right ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it fails because you might be left with nothing after taking an infinite number of subsequences. Consider, for instance, if each subsequence you take is every other element in the previous subsequence.